# How can I save the images in sequence?

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I save the images in sequence, example:

image01
image02
image03

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 

elements: driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "//img[@src]")

for element in elements:
     atributoSrc = imagem.get_attribute("src")
     #print(atributoSrc)
     urllib.request.urlretrieve(atributoSrc,r"C:\image\nome.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case images you want to save here are `atributoSrc` this can be done as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 

images = []

elements: driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "//img[@src]")

for element in elements:
     atributoSrc = imagem.get_attribute("src")
     images.append(atributoSrc)
     urllib.request.urlretrieve(atributoSrc,r"C:\image\nome.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to declare one `counter` variable and dynamically name the image file by using `f-Strings`.

```
counter = 1
for element in elements:
     atributoSrc = element.get_attribute("src")
     file_name = f"image{counter:02d}.jpg"  # 00, 01, 02, ...
     urllib.request.urlretrieve(atributoSrc, f"C:\\image\\{file_name}")
     counter += 1
```